# Synchronise video stream + eye tracker

Tags: ffmpeg, synchronization, rtp

I have quite a little experience with streaming video.
I am currently working on the following task:
I need to synchronize the streaming video (currently it is mpeg ts + h264) with the data received from the eye tracker.
From eye tracker I can get a timestamp when the data has been logged.
My idea is to get the time when the video frame was sent to the network and pick up the closest record from the eye tracker to it
Is it possible to get this frame information using ffmpeg ? I found information about the PTS and DTS of the frame, but it doesn't seem to be the same at all.
I also found that it is possible to get an NTP timestamp from the RTP protocol. It turns out that the information needs to be taken from the transport protocol?

Comment: are you talking about the actual date & time or within video elapsed time?

Comment: I think the actual date&time. 
Because the recording of video and data from eye tracker may not start at the same time

Comment: I doubt FFmpeg will give you what you want. You can try `-copyts` option but this requires the input stream timestamp to be the real time stamp rather than when the streaming started... Curious to know if gets you anywhere.

Comment: Also, remember that pts/dts are in timebase units. So you need to get the timebase of the stream and divide pts/dts by the timebase to get the seconds elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is similar to lipsync in RTCP.

When a RTCP SR record is received, SR data is used to update time synchronization information using NTP timestamp.

When you get the eye tracker sample you can use the incoming timestamp and compute an updated real-time timestamp.
Of course, I assume the eye tracker samples must provide either RTCP SR records or something similar enough.